# PDO fails to return MySQL search using COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf8mb4, collate

I have a simple PHP PDO query on a MySQL table which returns one result in phpMyAdmin console but fails to return any rows within PHP using the query below...
Why would/could there be a different result from within phpMyAdmin and from a PDO query?

```
$statement = $this->db->connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$arrResults = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In my dsn I have

```
;charset=utf8mb4
```

and also set

```
$this->connection->exec("SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;");
```

The WHERE part of the query is as follows... note the 'ø' character which causes the problem for PDO. If I remove it, the search works fine.

```
WHERE (R.last_name LIKE '%Schø%' OR R.first_name LIKE '%Schø%')
```

or

```
WHERE (R.last_name LIKE _utf8mb4 '%Schø%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci OR R.first_name LIKE _utf8mb4 '%Schø%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci )
```

Results returned in phpmyadmin:
[image: Results returned in phpmyadmin]

The searchable columns:
[image: The searchable columns]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've upgraded to PHP 8.0.9 and MySQL 8.0.26 and the issue has gone. I found that the issue was somehow connected to PDO's `bindParam` call as it was quoting UTF-8 somewhat incorrectly / incompatible way.

I didn't use `SET NAME utf8mb4` call at all, but specified `utf8mb4` on the PDO's DSN.

On MySQL side I set the schema / database, its tables and columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` (this is latest standard, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` should work as well).

Sharing my code that worked for me, so you can have an idea of what actually works.

```
<?php
    $text = 'verbündet';
    try
    {
        $database = 'german';
        $username = 'german';
        $password = 'blaB1A81a';
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$database.";charset=utf8mb4", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try
    {
        $text = strtolower($text);
        $data = [];
        $s = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `word` FROM `words_de` WHERE `word` = :word");
        $s->bindParam(':word', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $s->execute();
        $fetch = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($fetch === false)
        {
            $data = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $fetch['word'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```